# Mongoose query for documents from last 24 hours, only one document per hour

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am coding an app in which there are some weather sensors that send air's temperature and humidity to the server every 5 minutes.

I would like to draw a chart of how the temperature and humidity change i.e overnight. My idea is to draw the chart basing on data from last 24 hours.

I cannot figure it out by myself, so I thought maybe I could seek help here. Of course, each measurement document has a field called `createdAt` which has the timestamp of the moment it has been created.

I need to build a mongoose query that will retrieve measurements collected in the last 24 hours, but only take one measurement from each hour. With the 5min time interval with the device's measurements I will have 12 documents created every hour. I would like to retrieve only one of them per each hour.

So far I was able to come up with this (used `gt` to get the last 24 hours measurements, dont know how to get only one document per each hour):

`Measurements.find({ "createdAt": { $gt: new Date(Date.now() - 24*60*60 * 1000) } })`

Comment: What's your criteria for which document you want in each hour?  I don't think there's a magic bullet for this.  You'll just have to filter the results of the query you have to get the measurements you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregation

[this is a great article](http://hudsonburgess.com/2017/01/04/mongodb-first-doc-by-group.html) for how to group your documents then pick one item per document.

You also need to filter docs for last 24 hours, then project for find and `hour` from timestamp.

> If you need, lets say, last 48 hours, you need to group by hour and day.

Your query will something like this

```
collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$filter": {
      "createdAt": { $gt: new Date(Date.now() - 24*60*60 * 1000) }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "h": {"$hour" : "$createdAt"},
      "original_doc": "$$ROOT"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": { "hour": "$h" },
      "docs": { $push: "$original_doc" } 
    }
  },
  { 
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: { $arrayElemAt: ["$docs", 0] }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below aggregation to get first and last document from each hour.

`$sort` to order documents by createdAt followed by `$group` on hour to output first and last document for each hour.

`$$ROOT` is system variable to access the whole document.

```
Measurements.aggregate([
  {"$match" : {"createdAt":{"$gt":new Date(Date.now() - 24*60*60 * 1000)}}},
  {"$sort":{"createdAt":-1}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"$hour":"$createdAt"},
    "first":{"$first":"$$ROOT"},
    "last":{"$last":"$$ROOT"}
  }}
])
```

Comment: Great thanks  {"$gt":new Date(Date.now() - 24*60*60 * 1000)} for this logic

Answer (score 0):

It Works for me:

```
var pipeline = [
            {
                $match: {
                    $and: [
                        {createdAt: {$gte: startDate}},
                        {createdAt: {$lte: endDate}},
                        {eventType: 'update'}
                    ]
                }
            },
            {$sort: {createdAt: -1}},
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$person",
                    persons: {$push: "$$ROOT"}
                }
            },
            {
                $replaceRoot: {
                    newRoot: {$arrayElemAt: ["$persons", 0]}
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'people',
                    localField: 'person',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'person'
                }
            },
            {$unwind: "$person"}
        ];

        VisitEvent.aggregate(pipeline)
            .then(function (events) {ere
```