# Mongo sort query with last 24 hours condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

querying to mongodb collection to pinning last 24 hour object always come first with condition

```
[
   {
      "panel":"mobile",
      "createdAt":"2020-11-02T11:19:12+05:00"
   },
   {
      "panel":"web",
      "createdAt":"2020-11-02T11:16:12+05:00"
   },
   {
      "panel":"mobile",
      "createdAt":"2020-11-01T11:14:12+05:00"
   },
   {
      "panel":"web",
      "createdAt":"2020-11-02T11:13:12+05:00"
   },
   {
      "panel":"web",
      "createdAt":"2020-10-31T11:13:12+05:00"
   }
]
```

I need to do the query to always come first of last 24 hour data with condition where panel="web"

The expected result will be like this

```
[
   {
      "panel":"web",
      "createdAt":"2020-11-02T11:16:12+05:00"
   },
   {
      "panel":"web",
      "createdAt":"2020-11-02T11:13:12+05:00"
   },
   {
      "panel":"mobile",
      "createdAt":"2020-11-02T11:19:12+05:00"
   },
   {
      "panel":"mobile",
      "createdAt":"2020-11-01T11:14:12+05:00"
   },
   {
      "panel":"web",
      "createdAt":"2020-10-31T11:13:12+05:00"
   }
]
```

let suppose if I have panel : "mobile" at 4:05 pm and panel: "web" at 3:05 pm I need panel: "web" at first and this condition only applicable for the last 24 hours I don't need to apply this with older.

Comment: What was the issue here? Why don't you use `$sort` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb)

Comment: This is quite different, i need those object as well where panel="mobile" but panel="web" always comes first if it have in last 24 hours

Comment: this is your answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48244163/mongoose-query-for-documents-from-last-24-hours-only-one-document-per-hour